# Text selection in `asp.net` application not working in ie11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11

We are trying to move our current users to `ie11` from `ie9`. The application is based on `asp.net` technology. As part of testing
1)The first issue I have seen is text selection is not working in `ie11` when I deployed to development server. When I try to select the entire page gets selected.

I have tried to install update for `. net framework 4.5` on development server that didn't work either. The installation failed.

Comment: So do you have a question or just felt like commenting on issues you're having in an incredibly vague way?

Comment: What is the solution for making text selection work in ie11 in asp.net application ?

Comment: And do you care to provide code and samples of what's not working? You're asking me to debug an application I have not seen and a problem I cannot reproduce.

Comment: I cannot select text in the entire application .It is an intranet based application . sorry dman I cannot get the entire application code  . My intention was to see if anyone has faced the issue before.Text  selection works in ie9 but does not work in ie11.

Comment: Nope. I've migrated dozens of apps to support ie11. Never experienced this. Sounds like you have some incompatible js or some attribute like unselectable or Css disabling it. Can't really give you more than that without seeing anything. Try standard debugging techniques. If it happens everywhere, make a basic page with no js or css and see what happens. Then slowly add your files back and see when it dies.

Comment: Thanks dman.will try